# how to give CSRF in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have method to update, i test update via postman, in routing is in web.php not in api.php
if i using get in routing is it working, but i thing its not correct way, but when i using patch or put is showing "page expired" i know is it cause CSRF, but how i put csrf in controller ?
when i googling there is say

```
$request->session()->token().
```

bu how i use it

this is my code

route

```
Route::put('/customer/update/{id}', 'CustomerController@update');
```

controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
$customer = Customer::find($id);
$customer->name = $request->name;
$customer->save();
}
```

my endpoint

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/update/42?name=maria50
```

i using in postman, patch/put not working only get
thank for help before

Comment: Which version of laravel you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can use this to exclude CSRF protection for your path
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

But in production , you would use some form to post form data and there you can use **@csrf**

```html
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

Or you can set request header with value of CSRF
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

**'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'value'**